# Typescript Multi Dimensional Array's Values Not Updating (to null)

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, multidimensional-array, null

## What I am Doing

I am trying to create a Sudoku solver and generator in Vue. Right now, I have the solving algorithm set up, and just need to generate new problems. I am generating problems by creating a completed Sudoku problem (complete with no bugs), then I have to remove nodes so that there is still only 1 solution to the problem.

## The Problem

When I try to access a node from the multi-dimensional array that represents the board, and change it to null (what I am using to display a blank node), the board does not update that value. I am changing it with the following code: `newGrid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = null;` (where pos[0] is the row, pos[1] is the column , and newGrid is grid we want to mutate). Note that the array is an array with 9 arrays inside, and each of those arrays has 9 numbers (or null) which represent the values for that position in the grid. To elaborate on the bug, if I put a `console.log(newGrid)`, there are normal looking values, and no `null`.

## What I Know and Have Tried

I know it has to do with this specific line, and the fact that I am setting the value equal to `null` because changing null to another value (i.e. `newGrid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 0;`) works and changes the array. The reason I don't just use a value other than `null` is: null renders and nothing and other values (0) render as something (null nodes should be blank), null is simple to understand in this situation (the logic is node has null, node has nothing, node is blank), and null is already implemented throughout my codebase.

Additionally, if I use `console.log(newGrid[pos[0]][pos[1]])`, null (the correct output) is outputted, even though `console.log(newGrid)` shows a number there, not null. Also, oddly enough, this works for one specific node. In row 1 (indexing starts at 0), column 8, null is set. Even though the input (completed) grid is always different, this node is always set to null. Edit: this bug had to do with the input grid already having `null` here, so it actually doesn't let any nulls be set.

To summarize: I expect an array with a `null` in a few positions I update, but I get a number instead. Also, there are no errors when the Typescript compiles to Javascript or during runtime.

## Code

Given that I am not exactly sure where the problem may be (i.e. maybe I create the array wrong) I am including the minimum code with a pastebin link to the whole file ([this is the full code](https://pastebin.com/xW2URNyn)). To restate, the goal of this function is to remove nodes from the list (by replacing them with null) in order to create a Sudoku puzzle with one solution. The code on Stack Overflow only includes some of the whole file, and the pastebin link includes the rest.

```ts
//global.d.ts
type Nullable<T> = T | null;
type Grid = Array<Array<number | null>>;
```

```ts
import { Solver } from './Solve';
```

```ts
// Inside the function that does the main work
const rowLen: number = grid.length;
const colLen: number = grid[0].length;
let newGrid: Grid = grid; // Grid is a argument for this function
```

```ts
let fullNodes = GetFirstFull(grid, colLen, rowLen);
let fullNodesLen: number = fullNodes.length;
```

```ts
// Some stuff that figures out how many solutions there are (we only want 1) is excluded
if (solutions != 1) {
  fullNodesLen++;
  rounds--;
} else {
  newGrid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = null;
}
```

Note that if anything seems confusing check out the pastebin or ask. Thank you so much for taking the time to look at my problem!

Also, it isn't just 0 that works, undefined also makes it set correctly. So, this problem seems to be something with the null keyword...

**EDIT:**
Given that no one has responded yet, I assume: my problem is a bit hard, there isn't enough information, my post isn't good quality, or not enough people have seen it. To control the problem of not enough information, I would like to include the function that calls this function (just to see if that might be related).

```ts
generate(context: ActionContext<State, any>) {
    let emptyArray = new Array(9);
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
      emptyArray[i] = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];

    const fullGrid = Solver(emptyArray);
    const puzzle = fullGrid ? Remover(fullGrid, 6) : state.gridLayout;

    context.commit('resetBoard', puzzle);
  },
```

Note: If you aren't familiar with Vuex, what context.commit does is changes the state (except it is changing a global state rather than a component state). Given that this function isn't refactored or very easy to read code in the first place, if you have any questions, please ask.

To solve other potential problems: I have been working on this, I have tried a lot of `console.log()`ing, changing the reference (`newGrid`) to a deepcopy, moving stuff out of the if statements, verifying code execution, and changing the way the point on the `newGrid` is set (i.e. by using `newgrid.map()` with logic to return that point as null). If you have any questions or I can help at all, please ask.